# Multi-step registration with fragments and a single activity in MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I need to build a multi-step/multi-screen registration flow. I have 4 fragments for each screen that will be hosted in one activity and I am switching the fragments using the navigation component.

The problem is I am unable to figure out how to take the data from each screen at the end and make the API call in the final/last screen.

I am using ViewModel in each fragment for its own specific task and another ViewModel for the activity that handles navigation events etc. Any suggestion would be appreciated thanks ️

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to nest the Fragment destinations in a `<navigation` tag that represents the `registration graph`, then scope the ViewModel to the `NavBackStackEntry` of the `registration_graph`.